# How to read and write data in spark via an S3 access point

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am attempting to use an S3 access point to store data in an S3 bucket. I have tried saving as I would if I had access to the bucket directly:

```scala
someDF.write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite")
    .save("arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:000000000000:accesspoint/access-point/prefix/")
```

This returns the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: "arn:aws:s3:us-east-1:000000000000:accesspoint/access-point/prefix/"
```

I havnt been able to find any documentation on how to do this. Are access points not supported? Is there a way to set up the access point as a custom data source?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have provided the arn instead of the s3 URL. The URL would be something like this (assuming `accesspoint` is the bucket name):

```
s3://accesspoint/access-point/prefix/
```

There is a button in the AWS console if you are in the object or prefix, top right `Copy S3 URL`